# Calculating Color Moments

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

How can I calculate color moments with skimage? measure.moments provides some moments but I don't know how to calculate mean, variance and skewness in terms of them. For example I can use M00 returned from measure.moments and with dividing it by number of pixels I can obtain mean, but I'm not sure it's the right way.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by color moments? According to the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.moments) this function returns spatial moments, so M00 is not related to the mean color, but rather to the centroid of the shapes in the image.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Color moments are mean, variance and skewness of pixel intensities for each channel. There are 3 channels in a RGB image, so each of 3 features can be extracted from each channel. I want to extract these and use as features. I can do it by hard coding, but I thought that using a library yields better performance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_moments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute sample statistics for the pixels in an image using standard NumPy functions and function in the SciPy statistics package:

- [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) for the mean,
- [`numpy.var`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) for the variance,
- [`scipy.stats.skew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) for the skewness, or
- [`scipy.stats.moment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html) for arbitrary central moments.

You will have to compute these per channel.

Comment: Also I didn't understand difference between color and central moments. It seems that both are calculated about mean.

Comment: @Tolga: Moments are [well-known](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) in physics and statistics. Central moments are moments about the mean. “Color moments” is a term I have heard of for the first time in this question (and I’ve been working professionally with image for a very long time). It likely is used in this context to specify what the variable is that the moments are computed from. You can also compute moments in an image that include spatial information (which ties in with the meaning of moment if physics). This leads to size, position and shape measures of objects.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose best known central moments are those include spatial information.